# Line Renderer 2d Follow the edge

Tags: unity, 2d, collider, line-renderer

I am using mouse position to draw a line using line renderer 2d. What i want is when the line hits a collider it should start to draw on the edge of the collider rather than over the collider. Something like this:

[image]

The line renderer will still draw using mouse position. It will just draw on the edge of a collider and move in the direction of mouse postion.

Comment: When it gets to the end will it conform to the shape of the collider to reach the mouse position or will it simply extend in a straight line? If the former, maybe some A* path finding could help. Cool gif btw.

Comment: it will conform to shape of the collider to reach the mouse poistion

Comment: Have a search on google for a* pathfinding, I think that will solve your problem. There's tonnes of tutorials on youtube.

Comment: @mr-matt could help me with the code of this , i am still stuck on this